# Bufferedwriter not saving *everything* to file

Tags: java, java-io, bufferedwriter

I am somewhat new to java and was hoping that someone could help me. I have looked everywhere, but cannot seem to finder a solution.
I'm trying to save the result of a method into a file using bufferedwriter. The bufferedwriter itself works as it is saving some other strings, but when it comes to this function is just displays 'null'. Is is because the result of this method returns more than one string? How do I resolve this?
My code is as following:

**Bufferedwriter code:**

```
public static boolean saveStringToFile (String fileName, String saveString)
{
    boolean saved = false;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try
    {
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
    try 
    {
            bw.write(saveString);
            saved = true;
    }
    finally
    {
            bw.close();
    }

    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return saved;
}
```

**The function itself:**

```
public static void getNetDetails()
{
    try {
        Process net = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("lsof -i -n -P");
        BufferedReader netInput = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(net.getInputStream()));
    while ((netDetails = netInput.readLine()) !=null)
    {
        System.out.println(netDetails);
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

        }
        catch(IOException e) {
               System.out.println("exception happened - here are the details: ");
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
}
```

**Saving function to file using bufferedwriter**

```
public static void generateNetReport()
{
    saveStringToFile("Net.txt","here is the thing.." + "\n" + netDetails );
}
```

can someone please help with how I can save netDetails onto a file without it just displaying null??

Comment: You seem to be missing code. Where are you calling `generateNetReport` and `saveStringToFile` ?

Comment: saveStringToFile is the name of the bufferedwriter code, generateNetReport is created in the main function. the code provided above are just snippets of my original class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Edited.)

This is the problem, in `getNetDetails()`:

```
while ((netDetails = netInput.readLine()) !=null)
```

In other words, the method will *always* leave `netDetails` as null, unless there's an exception.

It would be better if `getNetDetails()` returned a string instead of setting a variable, and assuming it's meant to return the final line of the file, it should be something like:

```
String line = null;
String nextLine;
while ((nextLine = netInput.readLine()) != null) {
    line = nextLine;
}
return line;
```

You should *also* close the `InputStreamReader` in a finally block, and almost certainly *not* swallow the exception.

Comment: but `getNetDetails()` is defined as void... won't it be a compile error?

Comment: @amit - then have `getNDetDetails()` return the value, rather than just dumping it into a global variable.

Comment: sorry, i did mean netDetails and it is a static string. I have other static string that do get saved onto the file but not netDetails, and I dont understand why.

Comment: It shouldn't be named `getNetDetails()` if it doesn't return `netDetails`, and the problem remains that `netDetails` is null.

Comment: @Jon Skeet -thank you for your updated answer, it does now return the final line onto the file, but how do i get it to display the whole result rather than just the last line? Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @Sham: So you want to basically load the whole file into a string? It would be simplest to use Guava (http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) as you could then just use `CharStreams.toString(reader)`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet -Thank you for the suggestion of using CharStreams. My issue is now resolved! :)